# How do I use xplanet in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: gui, 23.10

I'm having trouble running xplanet and the current instructions on this site have been no help.  Can someone explain how to setup xplanet in Ubuntu 23.10?

Comment: Please add some information on what exactly you are doing, how you installed the software and what errors you get,

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: It looks like it was installed by `sudo apt install xplanet`